# Make animation happen when a section is in view using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am still learning web designing and I wanted to start an animation on a div which is in middle of the page. I searched for it but everywhere I found it using j-query. Is there any way it can be done using pure CSS and JavaScript.

```
<div>A lot of contents which take whole screen</div>
<div>Section where animation has to happen when come into view</div>
```

Please help if it can be done using javascript only and if not then what is the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY might be useful

Comment: No need to enter JS on every scroll. Instead use IntersectionObserver on the element you want to animate as it comes into view and remove the animation as it goes out of the viewport.

Comment: You could probably implement something like this, but since I don't know what type of animation you want, I cannot make this an answer. https://coolcssanimation.com/how-to-trigger-a-css-animation-on-scroll/

Answer (score 4):

#### I just searched like you did and found a pure `js` answer

### [REFERENCE](https://www.dev-tips-and-tricks.com/animate-elements-scrolled-view-vanilla-js)

```js
var elements;
var windowHeight;
document.getElementById('content').innerText = "A lot of content to fill up the page. ".repeat(500)

function init() {
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('.noanimfornow');
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
}

function checkPosition() {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var positionFromTop = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
//console.log(positionFromTop,windowHeight);
    if (positionFromTop - windowHeight <= 0) {
      element.classList.add('animateme');
      element.classList.remove('noanimfornow');
    }
        if (positionFromTop - windowHeight > 0) {/*newly added:Edit2*/
      element.classList.add('noanimfornow');
      element.classList.remove('animateme');
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkPosition);
window.addEventListener('resize', init);

init();
checkPosition();
```

```css
@keyframes myanim {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(.7, .7)
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animateme {
  animation: myanim 5s;
}
.noanimfornow {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>

<div class="noanimfornow">Section where animation has to happen when come into view</div>
```

- First for the div you need animation only when you scroll, set class to `noanimfornow` ,
- Next in `js` we check the position of scroll, and set the class to `animateme` when it reaches into view,
- We also check any resizing event and start `init` function if needed in `js`
- finally we put some animation for those in `css`

Comment: Hi. Seem `element.classList.remove('noanimfornow');` not works. When does it work?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi ,it does work properly, when you scroll to view it removes the class and adds another class `animateme`

Comment: Oh yes. good. but how to remove `animateme` after scrolling up? to this meaning that when `if (positionFromTop - windowHeight <= 0)` to be false, animation be removed, and again animation be active whenever we do scrolling down?

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi Just code what you said in words in the comment. The false of `<=` symbol, is true of `>` symbol.so make another statement like  `if (positionFromTop - windowHeight > 0) `,also change the values of what to remove and add(remove `animateme` and add `noanimfornow`), **I have done exactly this,see the edit 2**

Comment: It's great now. good job:)

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi if it helped you out then please mark it as solution (click grey tick and turn to green tick)

Comment: But it is not my question:/ :) you may have thought this because I asked so many questions. But I did upvote for you. I hope @Siddharth accepts that.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimi yes really i thought its your question anyway leaveit

Answer (score 2):

#### This answer does exactly the same as the other answer, but it uses `IntersectionObserver`

- > Thus "No need to enter JS on every scroll." - A Haworth's comment

#### This Code is referred from [here](https://coolcssanimation.com/how-to-trigger-a-css-animation-on-scroll/)

- also i have used Tschallacka's edit to remove copy paste (using `.repeat(500)` in js)

```js
var elements;
var windowHeight;
document.getElementById('content').innerText = "A lot of content to fill up the page. ".repeat(500)

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const square = entry.target.querySelector('.noanimfornow');

    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      square.classList.add('animateme');
      return; // if we added the class, exit the function
    }

    // We're not intersecting, so remove the class!
    square.classList.remove('animateme');
  });
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.animwrapper'));
```

```css
@keyframes myanim {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(.7, .7)
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animateme {
  animation: myanim 5s;
}

.noanimfornow {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<div class="animwrapper">
  <div class="noanimfornow">Section where animation has to happen when come into view</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent again. especially suggesting of  `repeat(500)` from Tschallacka is very good.